# VSC++2010: -Zm135

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, pch

I would like to read detailed description of -Zm135 Visual Studio 2010 command line option.
Briefly, this is an option to set when virtual memory for PCH is exceeded. Additionally, what is a meaning of -Zm letters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It specifies percentage of memory available for precompiled headers: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bdscwf1c%28v=vs.100%29.aspx